# MySQL Left Join on two tables on same column return NULL values

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table `entity_finantial_trxn`

[image]

and `finantial_trxn`

[image]

When I try two left Join them on same column, I get NULL values for one of them.

Query -

```
SELECT *
FROM `financial_trxn` ft
  LEFT JOIN entity_financial_trxn eft
  ON eft.financial_trxn_id = ft.id AND eft.entity_table = 'contribution'
  LEFT JOIN entity_financial_trxn eft1
    ON eft1.financial_trxn_id = ft.id AND eft1.entity_table = 'financial_item'
```

Why is it returning NULL for `entity_table` even if I have values for them for all the rows ?

Due to this I'm not getting the desired output as the additional Where clase to the above query hides the NULL row

```
WHERE (eft1.entity_table IS NOT NULL)
```

**Result :**
[image]

Comment: is there any way I could get both the rows as output ?

Comment: for `financial_trxn_id` the value in entity_table is null.

Comment: @Jens I'm sorry, but I didn't get you, the last image is the output which I'm getting here. Why the `entity_table` is NULL here eventhough I have all the entires filled for it in `entity_finantial_trxn` table ? SFLR

Comment: @Jens How can I get both the rows in the result as output after applying the where clause ?

Comment: Show your expected result

Answer (score -1):

your query is wrong , change your query to be:

```
SELECT *
FROM `financial_trxn` ft
  LEFT JOIN entity_financial_trxn eft
  ON eft.financial_trxn_id = ft.id 
 where eft.entity_table = 'contribution' OR eft.entity_table = 'financial_item'
```

Comment: @Strawberry poster does not know how add 2 condition with join, if you take care you will find the 2 table joined with the same condition

Comment: Respondent doesn't understand the effect of a where clause on an outer join